# whether need quotation marks with strings in simpleXML in php

Tags: php, string, quotation-marks

this is my php code to check whether a tag named $GEcode exsits as node in _.xml file: 
in line 4, when I write GEcode=$GEcode, it echo 'not exsits', when the quotation marks exsit(GEcode='$GEcode'), it return "exsits". I am confused, $GEcode is already a string, why still need quotation marks? 
(in the form, name="GEcode"; value = "GE1319")

```
1.<?php
2.$courselist = simplexml_load_file("_.xml");
3.$GEcode = $_POST['GEcode'];
4.$course=$courselist->xpath("child::course[GEcode='$GEcode']");
5.if(empty($course)){
6.echo "not exsits";
7.}
8.else{
9.echo "exsit";
10.}
11.?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the string that is being passed to xpath.  With the quotes, it's:

```
child::course[GEcode='GE1319']
```

without quotes, it's:

```
child::course[GEcode=GE1319]
```

this is invalid xpath syntax, since the value must be quoted.

Comment: What do you get from:   echo "child::course[GEcode='$GEcode']";